# How to tell if a set of simultaneous congruences is solvable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let's say <sub>we</sub> have a set of N simultaneous congruences that looks like this:

- x ≡ c<sub>1</sub>  (mod m<sub>1</sub>)
- x ≡ c<sub>2</sub>  (mod m<sub>2</sub>)
- ...
- x ≡ c<sub>N</sub>  (mod m<sub>N</sub>)

Currently, to check if this set has a solution I have to go through all possible pairs of congruences and test in each pair if the GCD(m<sub>i</sub>,m<sub>j</sub>) divides evenly the difference |c<sub>i</sub> - c<sub>j</sub>|. If in any of these pairs it does not divide evenly, I can stop the calculation and say that there is no solution for this set.

This method works, however it is very slow. I thought about using Chinese Reminder Theorem here, but it does not work since in my case m values are not necessarily relatively prime to each other.

Answer (score 1):

There may be heuristics, but in the worst case your simple algorithm is basically the best you can do. If you have $N$ congruences, then just consider the first ${N \choose 2}$ primes and let these label the edges on a complete graph connecting $N$ nodes. Then for each node $i$, define the modulus $m_i$ to be the product of the $N-1$ primes that label edges connecting to node $i$. Then let the given remainders be any choices of $c_i$ you want. Then every pair of distinct modulus $m_i,m_j$ have exactly one distinct prime in common in their factorizations, and there's no way to know if there's a solution to your congruence unless you test that pair, e.g. using your GCD method to find the common prime and then check that the prime divides the difference of remainders.